# "Broken" Local Repository - how can I notice? How can I stop it from happening?

Tags: java, maven

The Local Repository of our build server contained inconsistent data for a SNAPSHOT version of an artifact. This caused the build server to load an older timestamped version even if `-u` was set for `mvn`.

This behaviour worries me. Colleagues complained that you "cannot trust Maven builds". I need to do something about it.

Of course, I could just reload every artifact for every build (essentially ignoring the Local Repository) but this would take unnecessarily long.

Is there a way to determine if a Local Repository is "broken"?

(Please do not advise us to *not* use SNAPSHOTs on the build server -- we need to do this for at least one more year.)

EDIT:

- Our build server is Quickbuild, but it shouldn't matter too much because it is just checking out code and then calling Maven.
- The inconsistency was of the form that the files ending in -SNAPSHOT (the pom, jar, etc) were of different age. It should have kept a copy, but I did not, so I cannot give more details.
- The local repository is shared for all builds of about 2000 separate Java projects.

Comment: you're talking about "local repository of our build server" but aren't mentioning the build software you actually use, nor mention what kind of inconsistent data you had. Add those to the question. Also, are you sharing local repository between builds? For every build, or for some?

Comment: May this be a thread-safety issue?

Comment: The first thing having a local cache only per job base and never per Build Server base. Otherwise you share the local cache between jobs which makes them dependable on each other which will never work (local cache is not intended for thread-safety!)...Furthermore the question is what kind of dependencies you have in your build which are needed to be SNAPSHOT's? Do you have a multimodule build which is a SNAPSHOT or does a multi module build having dependencies outside the reactor? Apart from that do you use a repository manager?

Comment: The other question is: How do you define a "local repository "( which is reality a local cache) being broken? Based on which criterias?

Comment: @khmarbaise We obviously made a big mistake. We have about 2000 separate build jobs (because we have no multi-module builds yet), but we cannot have 2000 separate local repositories (storage capacity). The only solution that comes to my mind is to drop the local repositories for each and every build.

Comment: For the SNAPSHOTs: SNAPSHOT versions are used all over the place as dependencies for our integration test servers - this should be stopped after our Ant-compatability-legacy-synchronisation is over, but this will take 6-12 months.

Comment: @khmarbaise The effect is that even with parameter "-U", the latest SNAPSHOT is not drawn, but after the erasure of the files, the latest SNAPSHOT is drawn correctly. The files that I found were a strange mixture of old and new versions which obviously confused Maven.

Comment: @khmarbaise Any idea to have thread-safe local repository?

Comment: You could take a look here: http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html#concurrent-safe-local-repository  (But If i correctly remember Igor has mentioned that there is an issue in there..). Are those 2000 jobs for a single project ? Can you draw an example how that looks like ? A work-a-round could be to delete the part of the repository of each job itself. Furthermore hard disk space is cheap...? About which sizes are talking about ?

Comment: We have 2000 separate Java projects. Each of them produces an artifact (jar, war, ear). Each of them is a separate build job. We are aiming for multi-module projects, but at the moment we are stuck with this structure (that we inherited from our Ant builds). Having 2000 local repositories means that a lot of artifacts end up in multiple local repositories and it takes several months and a lot of discussions to get additional disk space for a server.

Comment: I also thought about deleting parts of the repository, but this is also not thread-safe: If I delete something while another build job needs it will probably break that build. As first aid, I could delete the local repository every night.

Comment: if you have 2000 jobs using the same local repository, I don't think it's any surprise that you have part of it out of sync, given that you will run jobs concurrently. Ideally you'd have shared local repository only for *released* artifacts, and snapshot dependencies in your repository manager - never locally in your build server repo.

Comment: Actually, we are using 25GB of available 500GB for the local repository, so it could work (at least for a while) to have 2000 local repositories.

Comment: @eis How I can tell Maven to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can. Usually what's being done is that you have build-specific local repos and a separate repository manager dealing with shared data. That's what I'd aim for if I were you.

Comment: btw. do you use 'mvn install' to install snapshot releases to that very same local repo you share between builds, or do you update the contents of the local repo only from repo manager?

Comment: The artifacts are installed in that very same local repo. Which is probably also no good idea.

Comment: Yes, I think that's just asking for concurrency issues.

Comment: Sorry but 500GiB for a build server is a really a little bit small..(we have 2 TiB for less jobs  about 500 at the moment)...Disucssion is from my point of view easy: safety first..which means having each jobs it's own cache makes it more realiable. Better would be having multi module builds...You can give the location of the local repository `-Dmaven.local.repo=XXXX` ...exchange of artifacts only via repository manager (a single SNAPSHOT repos is enough for that separation based on GAV)...and migration to real Maven based structures etc. will boost your builds...etc.

Comment: We have a single multi module build which comprises of 800+ modules...

Comment: We are running the whole build in 5 minutes...

Comment: It would be great if I could just "buy" disk space, but in reality I have to beg for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a summary from discussion in the comments: you seem to have 2000 separate builds reading from and installing to the same local maven repository, a directory within your build server. That's just asking for concurrency issues, as local maven repository is just a directory structure, lacking any mechanism to handle concurrent updates to directory structure.

Usually what's being done is that you have build job-specific local repos and a separate repository manager dealing with shared data. All created artifacts would be uploaded to repository manager, which handles concurrent requests as well. That's what I'd aim for if I were you.

If you insist on having local file-level sharing of artifacts, those should be at least only artifacts fetched from repo manager, not snapshot artifacts generated locally, as that will lead to concurrency issues.

Comment: Any short term suggestions? Getting additional disk space (something like 5 TiB as @khmarbaise suggests) will probably take at least half a year. We have a Nexus that handles all our artifacts. Maybe I should use a new local repository for every build, fill it from Nexus and delete it directly after the build...

Comment: @JFMeier yes, I'd start with that. You can also selectively reuse build job-specific repo between builds of the same job for *some* of the jobs, if you don't have the disk space to that for all the jobs.

Comment: I didn't talk about 5 TiB but I would at least go to 1 or 2 TiB...what I don't understand is why do you have so many jobs? Is each module of a multi module build a separate job? Wouldn't be easier to migrate into multi module builds which solves the module interdependencies? Deploy SNAPSHOT's into repository manager ? We have done the same thing (21 Component migrated into a single multi module build)...which solved all issues other things and boosted other things...

Comment: Every "module" is a separate job and we should go for multi-module projects in the future. But we are still in the process of migrating from Ant to Maven (at the moment, we have 800 Maven and 1200 Ant projects) and it will probably be mid-2018 until we can start introducing multi-module builds. The SNAPSHOTs are already deployed to Nexus which manages all our artifacts (Ant and Maven), so installing them in the local repository is somehow superfluous.

Comment: It sometimes hard to explain to outsiders that we have 100+ developers with so many (often very small) separate artifacts, and that every change in the general project structure is something that has to be very well prepared.

Comment: What is the problem of starting multi module builds? If you migrate from Ant to maven I would do that in one go...Furthermore I'm working in Env. with more than 150+ devs. Structure changes of course is hard but will improve the build and more important will simplify development in Eclipse/IDE where you can import the whole multi module build in one go...makes refactoring etc. simpler....and prevents more errors cause you could use the tools (IDE) to make renames etc. which is otherwise not possible....

Comment: If you want to migrate 100 Ant projects to one multi-module Maven project, you have to migrate all these projects in the same week. This means that all developers of the 100 projects need to be present and all problems of migration have to be solved beforehand. I value your opinion and your experience (which is much larger than mine), but doubt that this is trivial.

Comment: At the moment, I am thinking about having one local repository per thread, i.e. every build job "grabs" a local repository and holds it until the build has finished. As there are probably < 50 parallel builds, this could be less disk space consuming.

Comment: That sounds like one possible approach. Also, one option I haven't seen brought up is to have multiple build servers. I'm not familiar with Quickbuild, but for Jenkins for example it is standard practice to distribute build server instance to several slaves on several computers, and you having that many builds, I would think it would ease the load on lot of places. However based on your previous comments, it might not be possible in your environment.

Comment: (splitting to multiple servers is often good thing to do in general. It is not an attempt to solve the particular problem you're having.)